# PHP: Check if Key is equal to string

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working with a two-dimensional array, and as I'm iterating through each index of this array, I'm trying to check if the current key is equal to a string.

Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```
foreach($_POST['items'] as $index => $item){

    $key = key($item);

    if($key == 'image'){
        echo 'hello';
    }

}
```

This throws the error  **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

How do you check if the current key is equal to a particular string?

var_dump

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { ["paragraph"]=> string(4) "paragraph 1" } 
    [1]=> array(1) { ["paragraph"]=> string(4) "paragraph 2" } 
} 
array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { ["paragraph"]=> string(4) "paragraph 3" } 
    [1]=> array(1) { ["paragraph"]=> string(4) "paragraph 4" } 
}
```

Here is the element within the form with name `image`:

```
<div><input type="file" name="items[][image]" id="uploadImage" multiple></div>
```

**var_dump of dynamic form with 1 image input followed by 1 paragraph input**

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { ["paragraph"]=> string(11) "paragraph 1" } 
}
```

`var_dump` is not seeing the input with name `image`???

**Here is the form** Its contents are dynamically added from `<script>`

```
<form method="post" action="insert.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <textarea name="title"></textarea>

        <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" id="upload">
    </form>
```

One of the dynamic adding functions (this one is for image inputs)

```
    function addImage() {
    $("form").append('<div><input type="file" name="items[][image]" id="uploadImage" multiple></div>');
}
```

Comment: That error means `$_POST['items']` is not something you can loop through with `foreach`. Your first step should be to make sure it's actually an array.

Comment: What is the contents of the `$_POST['items']` variable? -- If you have not performed any processing on it then it is likely a String, and not an array.

Comment: `key($item)` and `key` is treated as a constant here / or a method which is unknown

Comment: There is other code within the `foreach` that, if I remove this `if` statement, will run just fine

Comment: I don't see how removing that `if` would have any bearing on the "Invalid argument supplied for foreach".

Comment: someone gave you an answer now, see that which I think is nothing more than a glorified testing method comment. I'm out

Comment: Appending the `var_dump` at the end of my post

Comment: No, it's within the `foreach` loop. Should I put it before the loop? I don't really know what I'm doing. Sorry, I'm a complete newbie

Comment: It doesn't change during the loop, so there's no need to do the same thing every time. But it doesn't matter. I tried to reproduce your error, I couldn't.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the formatting

Comment: If you var_dumped that inside the loop, then the error must have been gone.

Comment: I removed the `if` statement to do the var_dump. If I leave the `if` code, it will get the error

Comment: But if you're getting that error, you shouldn't get into the `foreach` loop at all. Are you sure the error is coming from this code? The error message should have a line number on it.

Comment: Put the `if` statement back, put the `var_dump` before the loop, and tell us what happens.

Comment: Also couldn't reproduce. Earlier you said "There is other code within the foreach", and I think the error is probably in that other code.

Comment: Okay, the `var_dump` is before the `foreach` now, and it's not getting the error. The `if` statement is not executing. `image` is nowhere to be seen in the array.

Comment: Adding the element within the form that has name `image` at end of my post

Comment: It's a dynamic form. I'm adding the `var_dump` when I add an image input followed by a paragraph input

Comment: It's like the var_dump doesn't recognize the element with name `items[][image]`

Comment: @Don'tPanic the only other code in the `foreach` is    `$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table (header, placement, datatype, typetext) VALUES (:header, :placement, :datatype, :typetext)");`

Comment: images deal with `$_FILES` not `$_POST` and lord only knows what the form tag holds and if there's a proper enctype. You have enough to go on now. No idea why you're using a file input while passing a text array after that. Your question has seen too many edits also. This also seems JS related as per a previous question of yours. This I suspected from the start, btw.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it's a dynamic form that holds mostly different kinds of text. The image inputs themselves have a text name that needs to be put into the database. All the stuff in the form is held in the `items` array so they each have an indexed position within the form. Are you saying that I can't have this file input held within the `items` array?

Comment: there's too much missing code. Again, file type inputs deal with `$_FILES`, and not `$_POST` with a POST form method and a proper enctype *to* handle files. Your question is unanswerable/unsolvable at this stage. You need to do something about that answer given below btw. No idea it's even posted in the first place.

Comment: My apologies for leaving out code - I was trying to be brief, and just going off of what I thought the important code would be. I was hugely wrong.

Comment: I've added the form itself and an example of the js that adds these form elements

Comment: @Fred-ii- The form has proper enctype. I understand the difference between `$_FILES` and `$_POST`, but I guess maybe I'm making a mistake in trying to lump these two within the same SQL statement? Should I handle the files in a separate statement altogether? My apologies for any annoyance - clearly I'm new to this and I'm a bit lost. I will try to more carefully consider what code I include with my question next time.

Comment: No need to use `key()` here, we already have it in `$index`.

Comment: @localheinz `$key = key($item);` seemed to work to get the name of the form input. Is there a more direct way? It wasn't getting the `image` name because that particular input was `type="file"`..so I guess the `$_POST['items']` in the `foreach` statement is not seeing that?

Answer (score 1):

Check if $_POST['items'] is an array

```
if(is_array($_POST['items'])){
    foreach($_POST['items'] as $index => $item){

        $key = key($item);

        if($key == 'image'){
            echo 'hello';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `is_array`. Without the `if` statement there are no errors.

Comment: Is the usage of `is_array` for testing purposes, or would you always use it when dealing with arrays?

Comment: @coffeebot You would use `is_array()` when you want to find out if a value is an array, context doesn't matter. For reference, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use [array_walk_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) which nicely takes care of the iteration for you; it is done implicitly and it's fast, too.  So, if $_POST["items"] were similar to the following array, this example code shows how to test for an element whose key is "key":

```
<?php

$arr = ["1" => "a",
        "2" => "b",
        "3" => [10 => "apple",
                11 => "cat", 
                12 => ["key" => "image" ]]];

if ( array_walk_recursive($arr, function($item,$key) {

     if ($key == "key") {
           echo "\nKey is $key and item is $item";
      }


})) { echo "\narray_walk_recursive rocks :)";  }
```

See live [code](https://3v4l.org/MSYEt).

The built-in function array_walk() saves the coder from also having to check whether an element represents an array or a scalar value since the function possesses that kind of detection.  The only thing that is required is to design the callback function, which in this case is an anonymous function.